# Can I always force CURL in PHP to connect using TLS v1.2 even when not available?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am working on a project where multiple Clients connect to a Central Server to retrieve updated information. The Central Server sometimes transmits data to the Clients. All the connections are made via CURL over HTTP(S) endpoints.

Some Clients are still using SSL v3 while some others have been configured for using the protocol TLS v1.2. Assuming the code below to establish a connection via CURL forcing TLS v1.2:

```
$req = 'val0=1&val1=1';
$endpoint = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$ch = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); //TLS v1.2
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_err = curl_error($ch);
if ($curl_errno) {
    //Error
    echo "Error ($curl_errno): $curl_err";
}else {
    //Success
    var_dump($res);
}
```

If the option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);` was omitted and if the `endpoint` was configured to use TLS v1.2, I would get a CURL Error 35 (SSL Connection Error). In this example I used the PayPal IPN Endpoint because that's the one I've been looking at for testing. For the moment, the Sandbox environment only accepts connections with TLS v1.2, if I changed the endpoint to "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" and if the `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` was set to 5 (TLS v1.1) or to SSL v2/v3, I would get the same SSL Connection Error. However, the production environment of PayPal (for the moment) seems to accept connections with any protocol.

I've been making some tests with other HTTPS endpoints where TLS v1.2 was **not** available and I was surprised to see that even if I forced TLS v1.2 with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);` I got no errors and the request was successful. This has been tested with various versions of `OpenSSL` and `NSS`.

My question is: considering the situation where someone may support (and/or require) TLS v1.2 and where someone doesn't support TLS but only SSL, is it safe to always tell CURL to use the SSL Version TLS v1.2? Of course I don't know if the Endpoint to which I'm connecting supports TLS v1.2, so I'm trying to avoid the CURL requests to fail ever. In which cases could I face errors/problems? Any explanation would be much appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--ssl "Try to use SSL/TLS for the connection. Reverts to a non-secure connection if the server doesn't support SSL/TLS." - It's for `libcurl` but this makes me think that when the protocol is not supported, the connection is reverted to a supported protocol. My tests should confirm all this but I did not ask a question to answer it by myself. Comments are still appreciated!

Comment: well, if the endpoint doesn't support the protocol you're telling curl to use, then curl's going to HAVE to fail the request...

Comment: @MarcB thanks for the comment. That's what I thought but I did a lot of CURL requests forcing the protocol TLS v1.2 to endpoints not supporting TLS v1.2 and they were successful. These endpoints were using versions of OpenSSL or NSS that would support TLS v1.2 but it was not enabled so the protocol was reverted to SSL v3 (result was tested with `curl_getinfo()`).